# Comparing two arrays in PHP foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, codeigniter-2

What's the best way to compare both two arrays to each other in a foreach loop ?

I have two arrays, which one holds a boolean values and other one represents the real values.

First one of the arrays is some sort of configuration file where I tell what field is a required one `TRUE` or an optional `FALSE`:

```
$rules = array(
    'fieldname1' => TRUE,
    'fieldname2' => FALSE,
    'fieldname3' => TRUE,
    'fieldname4' => TRUE,
    'fieldname5' => FALSE,
    'fieldname6' => FALSE,
    'fieldname7' => TRUE,
    'fieldname8' => TRUE
);
```

And the other array which holds incoming data to be worked out:

```
$fields = array(
    'fieldname1' => 'some value',
    'fieldname3' => 'some value',
    'fieldname4' => 'some value',
    'fieldname7' => 'some value',
    'fieldname8' => 'some value'
);
```

How do I make a check in `foreach()` loop, so the `$fields` array is going to compare each of its  `fieldnameX` or (keys/indexes) with the other array named `$rules` ?

For example: `$rules['fieldname1']` is required as it have a bool `TRUE`. So in `foreach($fields as $field)`, the `$field` named `fieldname1` should not be empty, null or false, if so, show an error.

This is a function I did so far which is not doing exactly what I want:

```
private function check_field_required_exist( $fields )
{
    // Read rules from config to work with them accordingly
    $rules = config_item('flow.format')[$fields['format']];

    // Run throught the rules
    foreach( array_keys($rules) as $field )
    {
        // Check wheter key existance is failed
        if( !array_key_exists($field, $fields) )
        {
            // Checking failed, terminate the process
            die('Required field: "'. $field .'" for requested format: "'.$fields['format'].'" does not exists.');
        }
    }

    // Everything is alright
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Goes through all the rules
foreach($rules as $key => $value) 
{
  // access all fields that are marked as required i.e key set as TRUE
  if ($value) 
  {
    //for those whose value is TRUE, check whether the corresponding field is set or
    // whether it is empty (NULL,false)
    if(!isset($fields[$key]) || empty($fields[$key]))
    {
      die('Required field does not exist');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Was that simple... I will make a couple tests to ensure it does 100% what I asked for.

Comment: You do realise this is pretty much the exact same thing I posted?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($fields as $field => $value)
{
    if (array_key_exists($field, $rules) && $rules[$field] === true)
    {
        if (!$value || $value == "" || $value === null)
        {
            die(); // return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can play around with the array functions in PHP. First thing I would do is to apply [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) on your rules array. That way, you will only keep the TRUE values (and their indexes, since array_filter keep the index/value association). 
Then I would use [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) to keep only the fields of interest in your fields var. And again array_filter with a custom callback to perform the verification you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

## USING [PHP Array Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php):

```
$rules = array('name' => TRUE, 'phoneNumber' => TRUE, 'age' => FALSE);
$submittedFields = array( 'name' => 'aspirinemaga', 'age' => 38, 'phoneNumber' => '');

$requiredFields = array_keys(array_filter($rules));
$validFields = array_keys(array_filter($submittedFields));

$missingFields = array_diff($requiredFields, $validFields);
```

Given

```
$rules = array('name' => TRUE, 'phoneNumber' => TRUE, 'age' => FALSE);
$submittedFields = array( 'name' => 'aspirinemaga', 'age' => 38, 'phoneNumber' => '');
```

PhoneNumber is wrong here.

```
$requiredFields = array_keys(array_filter($rules));
```

This gives you the keys of all rule elements that are `TRUE`.

```
$validFields = array_keys(array_filter($submittedFields));
```

Same here, your definition of what's ok is the same as [php truth table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for boolean conversion. If you have a more advanced check, you could pass a function name into [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) (see below).

```
$missingFields = array_diff($requiredFields, $validFields);
```

This will get you all the fieldNames that exist in `$requiredFields` but are not in `$validFields`.

### More advanced validation

```
$rules = array('name' => 'MORE_THAN_3', 'phoneNumber' => TRUE, 'age' => 'POSITIVE');
$submittedFields = array( 'name' => 'aspirinemaga', 'age' => 38, 'phoneNumber' => '');

$requiredFields = array_keys(array_filter($rules));

function validateField($key, $value){

    // get the rule (assuming no submittedFields that have no rule)
    $rule = $rules[$key];
    
    switch($rule){
        case 'MORE_THAN_3': return strlen($value) > 3; break;
        case 'POSITIVE': return $value > 0; break;
    }

    // in case of TRUE/FALSE
    return TRUE;       
}

$validFields = array_keys(array_filter("validateField", $submittedFields, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));
$missingFields = array_diff($requiredFields, $validFields);
```

If you wanted to do a more advanced validation, you can integrate that nicely into above solution.

Say you wanted `name` to be more than 3 characters and `age` to be positive. Write it into your rules:

```
$rules = array('name' => 'MORE_THAN_3', 'phoneNumber' => TRUE, 'age' => 'POSITIVE');
$submittedFields = array( 'name' => 'aspirinemaga', 'age' => 38, 'phoneNumber' => '');
```

Required Fields are still the same (to check if one is missing).

```
$requiredFields = array_keys(array_filter($rules));
```

Now your validate function would be something like:

```
function validateField($key, $value){

    // get the rule (assuming no submittedFields that have no rule)
    $rule = $rules[$key];
    
    switch($rule){
        case 'MORE_THAN_3': return strlen($value) > 3; break;
        case 'POSITIVE': return $value > 0; break;
    }

    // in case of TRUE/FALSE
    return TRUE;       
}
```

Pass that into `array_filter` and add to `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` Flag:

```
$validFields = array_keys(array_filter("validateField", $submittedFields, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));
```

And your missing Fields stays the same.

```
$missingFields = array_diff($requiredFields, $validFields);
```

*This will only work in PHP 5.6+ (because ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH). Not tested, should work.*

Answer (score 0):

```
$requiredField = array();
foreach($rules as $key=>$value) {
    if($value == true && (!isset($fields[$key]) || $fields[$key] == "" )) {
        $requiredField[] = $key;
    }
}
if(count($requiredField) > 0) {
    echo implode(',',$requiredField)." Are Required";
    die;
}
```